# How to break table rows into new columns?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I made the mistake of structuring some Access tables ineffectively as I was developing a database to store data for my company.

The data pushes and pulls from various models, so I need to restructure the old "labor" tables (each proposal has a labor table) so that any data can be retrieved in the future.

I'm brand new to SQL. I've tried doing this a few different ways (APPEND, ALTER...ADD COLUMN, and others). I think that SELECT...INTO is the way to go at this point, but I still can't get it quite right.

In the old table structure, the first field is "Period." All of the records reappear once for every period. The LCAT, Company, and Salary fields are exactly the same for each period. The only values that change from period to period are the 2 right columns.

I need to restructure these by copying the hours and DLRate values for each period after the 1st into new columns (and rename the Hours/DLRates columns. I've included what I have so far.

Thanks in advance!

```
| Period LCAT Company Salary Hours DLRate |
|-----------------------------------------|
|    1   LCAT1 Comp1   77000  1723  $37.02|
|    1   LCAT2 Comp1   81000  1723  $38.94|
|    1   LCAT3 Comp2   81000  1723  $50.00|
|    2   LCAT1 Comp1   77000  1800  $38.02|
|    2   LCAT2 Comp1   81000  1800  $39.94|
|    2   LCAT3 Comp2   81000  1800  $51.00|
```

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub RedoTables()
Dim sTbl As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim sTemp As String
Dim intA As Long, intB As Long
Dim arrCols() As String: arrCols() = Split("Hours,DLRate", ",")

sTbl = "Labor"

For intB = 1 To 2
    `enter code here`For intA = LBound(arrCols) To UBound(arrCols)
        sTemp = "(SELECT " & arrCols(intA) & " FROM [" & sTbl & "] " _
            & "WHERE Period = " & intB & ") " _
            & "AS P" & intB & "_" & arrCols(intA)
        Debug.Print sTemp
        sSQL = sSQL & sTemp

        If intA < UBound(arrCols) Or intB < 1 Then sSQL = sSQL & ", "
    Next
Next
sSQL = "SELECT" & sSQL & " " _
    & "INTO [" & sTbl & "test] " _
    & "FROM [" & sTbl & "]; "
DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
End Sub
```

When I execute the SQL, I am getting an error that states "at most one record can be returned by this subquery"....

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Very good decision,to repair the data structure first!`Debug.Print sSQL`before execution, as sql code is wrong. Paste result into the query designer to see what is wrong.

Comment: Do some research on "database normalization", as you still miss some insights there. E.g. only Period and Hours are always the same -> they belong to a seperate table. Table Labor only contains a foreign-key (FK) to this table. I don't know what LCAT is, but seems to be connected with customer -> new table, reference FK . Customers should have their own table, just reference them by FK.  Salary is connected to LCAT (what seems to need own table too)?,

Comment: @Ben . . . Before and after data would help.

Comment: Part of normalization would mean one table for labor, not one for each proposal.